# Linking to the "head" revision of a document in Subversion

Tags: svn

Is there a way to establish an HTTP reference to the head instance of a document in subversion...

For example this reference links to a specific version of a document:

> http://csvn.example.​com:8888/viewvc/prod​uct-doc/trunk/Platfo​rm/Requirements/Admi​nistration%20Guide.d​ocx?revision=6988​&view=co

I would like to establish a link that always references the latest and greatest version...

Comment: We are using CollabNet Subversion Edge to generate the web interface

Comment: Have you tried with revison=head?

Comment: Yep... I get an error...

Comment: revision=HEAD works... case sensitive... I knew it had to be simple... thanks

Comment: This appears to be true for viewvc, but if you're serving the repository with Apache, you can just link to the URL of the file (no querystring parameters) and you'll always get the HEAD revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
revision=HEAD
```

Or more fully:

```
http://csvn.example.​com:8888/viewvc/prod​uct-doc/trunk/Platfo​rm/Requirements/Admi​nistration%20Guide.d​ocx?revision=HEAD
```

Apparently our version of CollabNet Subversion Edge is case sensitive...

Answer (score 1):

If you use "plain" web-interface for accessing repoisitory (pure hand-made Apache or VisualSVN Server) without fancy and power frontend (ViewVC|Sventon|WebSVN) URL of any object in repository can be also used in ordinary web-browser - and parameter-less URL will show **always** the **latest** revision of object

```
>svn info http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.fr.txt
Path: Hello.fr.txt
Name: Hello.fr.txt
URL: http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.fr.txt
...
Revision: 37
...
Last Changed Rev: 35
```

Used in browser http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.fr.txt will show 35 revision of file, which stored in HEAD revision of http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a tag for your documents:

```
$ REPO=http://svn.firstVegiBank.com/svn
$ svn cp -r23393 $REPO/trunk/docs $REPO/tags/1.3.2/docs
```

Now, in your instructions, you can say:

> You can find the required documentation at http://svn.firstVegiBank/svn/tags/1.3.2/docs/instructions.html. This will explain the whole process.

Otherwise, I recommend to setup [Sventon](http://sventon.org) or [ViewVC](http://viewvc.org). These are HTTPd browsers for your Subversion repository. These will let you specify the exact revision of a file in their URL. Plus, it's a friendlier interface. You can even specify a URL that directly downloads the file.

I find Sventon easier to setup. Plus, Sventon doesn't have to run on the same server as your Subversion repository.

Answer (score 0):

- If you use VisualSVN Server, you can use such URL to link to the HEAD (latest) revision of a document in web interface:

  http://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#tortoisesvn/view/head/trunk/doc/source/Hacking.txt
- To link to the same document in revision r1234, use such URL (note that head part changed to r1234 revision specifier:

  http://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#tortoisesvn/view/r1234/trunk/doc/source/Hacking.txt